# pre-commit hook does not echo on terminal

Tags: bash, echo, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am trying to run a script with pre-commit hook. Here is my script:

build_script.sh

```
 #! /bin/bash
 echo "Stage 1: Preparing CMake configuration"
```

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
fail_fast: false
  - repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: Generate build 
        name: Generate build 
        entry: sh build_script.sh
        language: system
        always_run: true
        pass_filenames: false
```

I can see when I run command `git commit -m "message"`, the hook calls the script and `Generate build` will Pass. However, I do not see the echo on the terminal. I would like to see the message, `"Stage 1: Preparing CMake configuration"`. What is wrong with this setup?

Comment: Strange. Seems the hook framework was catching the stdout. Just for debugging: You also don't see any output if you configure the _entry_ as `sh -x build_script.sh`?

Comment: BTW (not important here, just for completeness): You are tagging this question by _bash_, but you don't run your script as bash. Bear this in mind if you want to use one day bash-specific features.

Comment: @user1934428 it does not work even with `sh -x build_script.sh` as entry point

Comment: This means that the trace produced by `-x` also does not show up? This is IMO strange design of pre-commit, because stderr is usually used to signal an error, and I find it odd that pre-commit hides stderr as well....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pre-commit takes a bit from unix philosophy here -- it is silent unless there is a problem (by default).

if your script fails then the output will be displayed

you can also use `--verbose` to show the full output (for debugging) and optionally set [`verbose: true`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-verbose) on  your hook itself.  **note**: these are both debugging options and are not intended for use outside that -- we've found that when hooks are noisy contributors tend to ignore *all* of the output

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit